# How to set a nested use of an XML namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces, schema

We have defined a namespace `xmlns:abc="http://example.org/ns/abc"` and an XML schema for it. This XML schema defines elements and data types.

This `abc` XML schema includes

```
<xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

which allows to use elements from an other namespace.

Next we have defined a namespace `xmlns:testing="http://example.org/ns/testing"` and an XML schema for it. This testing XML Schema imports the abc namespace and its XML schema by `<xs:import namespace="http://example.org/ns/abc" schemaLocation="abc.xsd"/>` as some of the data types defined in the abc namespace should be used for elements of the testing namespace.

Finally we've created an XML document making use of both namespaces and XML Schemas:

```
<rootElement xmlns="http://example.org/ns/abc" xmlns:testing="http://example.org/ns/abc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.org/ns/abc abc.xsd http://example.org/ns/testing testing.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <abcElement1>Some text</abcElement1>
    <testing:element1/>
</rootElement>
```

Validating this XML document we get errors "...element name... is a already declared" pointing at https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#sch-props-correct

This sounds like it is not possible to import a namespace with its schema into another namespace if this other namespace is used on the context of the first namespace/schema - a kind of nested reuse of it.

Is there a better way of nesting the abc namespace/schema or is the only alternative to split the abc namespace into one holding only elements and another, new one holding data type definitions and importing this data-type-namespace into the testing namespace/schema?

Here are the full examples:
abc.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="http://example.org/ns/abc" targetNamespace="http://example.org/ns/abc" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="rootElement">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="abcElement1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="abcEntity" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="EntityType1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="identifier" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

testing.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://example.org/ns/testing" xmlns:abc="http://example.org/ns/abc" targetNamespace="http://example.org/ns/testing" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://example.org/ns/abc" schemaLocation="abc.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="element1">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="person" type="abc:EntityType1" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="company" type="abc:EntityType1" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Example document 1 - referencing the schemas as local files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootElement xmlns="http://example.org/ns/abc" xmlns:testing="http://example.org/ns/testing"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.org/ns/abc abc.xsd http://example.org/ns/testing testing.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <abcElement1>Some text</abcElement1>
    <testing:element1>
        <testing:person>
            <identifier>http://example.com/entity/134134234</identifier>
        </testing:person>
    </testing:element1>
</rootElement>
```

... and this document can be validated, no error is thrown.

Then I uploaded the abc.xsd to one of my web sites and replace the local file name by its URL:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.org/ns/abc http://data.newsit.biz/fortesting/abc.xsd http://example.org/ns/testing testing.xsd"
```

... and the example document with this xsi:schemaLocation throws the error mentioned above. 
Why makes having an XML Schema as local file or as web resource a difference?

Software used for validation: XMLspy 2018 rel2 sp1

The error messages:

- File exampleDocument2.xml is not valid
- The schemas referenced by xsi:schemaLocation or xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attributes at element  are not valid.
- 'abc:rootElement' is already declared.
- a link to https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#sch-props-correct
- This "... already declared and the link is shown also for abc:EntityType1

Comment: Your XML file validates successfully for me using my trusty Xerces-based XSD validator for both local and remote `abc.xsd` XSDs.  What XSD processor are you using, and what are the exact error messages you're receiving?  Please [edit] your question and copy-and-paste the exact error messages as quotes in rather than paraphrasing them.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same '{element} is already declared' error with my environment (XMLSpy 2017 sp2 x64 / Win 7 Ent v6.1 build 7601 sp1).

However my simple python validation script using lxml / etree validates correctly for both the local and remote schema cases.

Answer (score 0):

Altova support provided this explanation for the thrown error:

The testing.xsd defines by the xs:import the location of the abc XML schema as (local) abc.xsd, as strict URL file://abc.xsd

The exampleDocument1 defines by the xsi:schemaLocation the location of the abc XML schema as (local) abc.xsd, as strict URL file://abc.xsd

In this context the location of the abc schema - expressed as URLs - is the same in both files: file://abc.xsd

The exampleDocument2 defines by the xsi:schemaLocation the location of the abc XML schema as http://data.newsit.biz/fortesting/abc.xsd

In this context the locations (URLs) of the abc schema are different and XMLspy interprets this as different schemas and throws errors about having a definition for e.g. rootElement in two different schemas.

Action of our group: to be able to use the web location of the abc schema http://data.newsit.biz/fortesting/abc.xsd in the XML document we had to use this URL also in the testing.xsd. Then the exampleDocument2 document was validated as correct.